# VS2012: InstallShield LE 2013: Dependent assemblies copied only once

Tags: visual-studio-2012, setup-project, installshield-le, installshield-2012

Facing an issue with IS LE 2012 Spring & 2013 LE as well. I have VS 2012 solution with one common project (A) and several projects (B, C, D etc..,) referencing the common project. When I add a IS setup project and include project B's primary output, a setup file is created with project B's output and also project A's output. This is perfectly fine. But when I starting adding different folders within the same setup project to include project C & D's output, the output of the common project is copied to ONLY one of the projects whereas the expected behavior is to have the common projects output to all the projects that are referring it.

When I remove the project that has project A's output from setup and build again, project A's output magically appears in some other project's output. It appears that IS has some sort of flag to the files that needs to be copied and ignore the file once it is copied to one location?

The dependency scan on each project's output seems to show all the files correctly but misses them when it is copied over. I even tried adding the common project's (proj A) primary output to all other projects that are referring it but still the assemblies are not copied over.

Any suggestions? (apart from uninstalling InstallShield to make effective use of my hard drive space)